# Outlook Add-in Support on Mobile Web Browsers

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins

I've been developing an Outlook add-in that successfully integrates with the native Outlook apps on iOS and Android. However, I've encountered a challenge when it comes to accessing the add-in via mobile web browsers, such as Safari or Chrome.

Despite thorough documentation review and adjustments to ensure mobile compatibility, I've noticed that the UI for opening add-ins does not appear in mobile web browsers. This led me to question whether Outlook add-ins are supported when accessed through mobile web browsers or if this capability is limited to native app integration only?

I've followed the guidelines for mobile support, ensuring the add-in declares MobileFormFactor in its manifest and adheres to UI and functionality standards for mobile devices.